# Quickblox create session being called through an intent service

Tags: android, quickblox, intentservice, android-intentservice

I am trying to schedule an `Alarm` using `AlarmManager` which tries to recreate the `QuickBlox` session every two hours. I am calling an `IntentService` in the background via the `AlarmManager`.

Following is the piece of code which crashes:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    String APP_ID = "xxxx";
    String AUTH_KEY = "xxxx";
    String AUTH_SECRET = "xxxx";
    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY,AUTH_SECRET);
    if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()){
        QBChatService.init(getApplicationContext());
    }

    ChatService.getInstance().chatCreateWriteSessionWithoutPlay(getApplicationContext());}
```

---

The definition of `chatCreateWriteSession` is as follows:

```
public void chatCreateWriteSessionWithoutPlay(final Context ctx) {
        chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
        // Create QB user
        final QBUser user = new QBUser();

        user.setLogin(AppController.getInstance().getCHAT_ID());
        user.setPassword(AppController.getInstance().getCHAT_PASSWORD());
        QBAuth.createSession(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle args) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {

            }
        });
    }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

all methods which return result in QBEntityCallback perform it on main Ui thread. Just use synchronous type of method, like  QBSession  session= QBAuth.createSession(QBUser user) to return result on the same thread as android service has started.